# access javascript array element by JSON object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array that looks like this

```
var Zips = [{Zip: 92880, Count:1}, {Zip:91710, Count:3}, {Zip:92672, Count:0}]
```

I would like to be able to access the Count property of a particular object via the Zip property so that I can increment the count when I get another zip that matches. I was hoping something like this but it's not quite right (This would be in a loop)

```
Zips[rows[i].Zipcode].Count
```

I know that's not right and am hoping that there is a solution without looping through the result set every time?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with it? Can you show your loop, and the `rows` object?

Comment: `Zips[1].Zip` would be `91710`. Since your zipcodes in there are VALUES, not keys, you can't use them as a direct array lookup. You'd have to scan every object in that array and match against the zip values.

Comment: I don't know about zipcodes but is "0265" a valid zipcode? If so be careful when using them as `Numbers` you will lose the leading `0`s.

Comment: each objects inside the {} is an object of Zips, so yeah - you don't need to loop, but you have to know the placement as what @MarcB pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

> I know that's not right and am hoping that there is a solution without
>   looping through the result set every time?

No, you're gonna have to loop and find the appropriate value which meets your criteria. Alternatively you could use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
var filteredZips = Zips.filter(function(element) {
    return element.Zip == 92880;
});
if (filteredZips.length > 0) {
    // we have found a corresponding element
    var count = filteredZips[0].count;
}
```

If you had designed your object in a different manner:

```
var zips = {"92880": 1, "91710": 3, "92672": 0 };
```

then you could have directly accessed the `Count`:

```
var count = zips["92880"];
```

Comment: I figured that was the case and am in the process of writing the loop but was hoping for a simpler solution. Oh well, thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: You could also use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method as shown in my answer which would avoid you the need of writing a loop. This is a native method that might be more optimized but don't expect an O(1) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

In the current form, you can not access an element by its ZIP-code without a loop.

You could transform your array to an object of this form:

```
var Zips = { 92880: 1, 91710: 3 }; // etc.
```

Then you can access it by

```
Zips[rows[i].Zipcode]
```

To transform from array to object you could use this

```
var ZipsObj = {};
for( var i=Zips.length; i--; ) {
  ZipsObj[ Zips[i].Zip ] = Zips[i].Count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of mistakes in your code.

1. Your array is collection of objects
2. You can access objects with their property name and not property value i.e `Zips[0]['Zip']` is correct, or by object notation `Zips[0].Zip`.

If you want to find the value you have to loop

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the format of the array Zips and its elements

```
var Zips = [{Zip: 92880, Count:1}, {Zip:91710, Count:3}, {Zip:92672, Count:0}];
var MappedZips = {}; // first of all build hash by Zip
for (var i = 0; i < Zips.length; i++) {
    MappedZips[Zips[i].Zip] = Zips[i];
}
```

MappedZips is `{"92880": {Zip: 92880, Count:1}, "91710": {Zip:91710, Count:3}, "92672": {Zip:92672, Count:0}}`

```
// then you can get Count by O(1)
alert(MappedZips[92880].Count);

// or can change data by O(1)
MappedZips[92880].Count++;
alert(MappedZips[92880].Count);
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/juliarechkunova/BU7Be/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getZip(zips, zipNumber) {
  var answer = null;

  zips.forEach(function(zip){
    if (zip.Zip === zipNumber) answer = zip;
  });

  return answer;
}
```

This function returns the zip object with the Zip property equal to zipNumber, or null if none exists.

Answer (score -1):

did you try this?

```
Zips[i].Zip.Count
```

Comment: `Count` is not a property of `Zip`.